# В датафрейме при преобразовании даты, она неправильно преобразуется

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Собственно если преобразовать дату скажем из `20140106` то получим `1/01/1970`. И это конечно же неправильно. Не пойму где ошибка.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('200524.csv')
df2.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Counte']

df2['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
del df2['Date'] 
df2['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Data'], format='%Y-%m-%d') \
                 .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').str.lstrip("0")
```

[Данные](http://zalil.su/8044598).

Comment: почему не правильно? pandas не может читать ваши мысли и преобразовывать строку в непонятном формате так, как вам хочется. Ваш файлообменник не отдает файл, кстати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df2['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'].astype(str))
```

---

[pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) - очень умная функция которая старается распознать дату в самых разных форматах.

В большинстве случаев на вход данной функции передают элементы строковых типов данных.

В вашем случае вы, похоже, передаете в качестве элементов целое число. Если передать `pd.to_numeric()` элементы с целыми числами, то функция воспримет это как число наносекунд, прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

Пример:

```
In [7]: pd.to_datetime([20140106])
Out[7]: DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 00:00:00.020140106'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
# NOTE: --------------------------------->  ^^^^^^^^^
```